# inherit javascript function prototype outside it closure

Tags: javascript, closures, prototype, chaining

I am using JavaScript prototype chaining technique to chain functions as shown below:

```
var foo = (function () {
    function fn(arg) {
        if (!(this instanceof fn)) {
            return new fn(arg);
        }
        this.arg = arg;
        return this;
    }
    var func = function (element) {
        return fn(element);
    };
    fn.prototype = {
        bar: function () {
            return this;
        }
    }
    func.functions = fn;
    return func;
}());
```

I would like to know how to access `fn.prototype` so I can add more functionality to the `foo` prototype outside its closure.

If I just simply do as follows, it won't work:

```
foo.prototype.baz = function () {
     alert(this.arg);
}
foo("hello").baz();
```

However if `fn` assigned to the `foo` (`func.functions = fn;`) as it shown in the `foo` private closure I can do as follow and it will works:

```
foo.functions.prototype.baz = function () {
     alert(this.arg);
}
foo("hello").baz();
```

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you sure you meant `baz` instead of `bar`

Comment: Also the line, `func.functions = fn` achieves nothing in this context, since you do not use `fn` with `this.fn` within the `func` body

Comment: You can exploit the fact that object are passed by reference and not by value and do something like this: `func.prototype = fn.prototype;` so when altering `foo`'s prototype `fn`'s prototype gets altered as well!

Comment: yes, baz is the new function i would like to chain. to be honest i found it difficult to explain the situation, hopefully it makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are un-necessarily overcomplicating this. You can chain by simply doing this:

```js
const foobar = function(){return this} // Initialize a new Object
const foo = text => {
    const me = new foobar()
    me.text = text
    me.bar = a => (alert(me.text+": "+a), me)
    return me
}

foo('A').bar('Test').bar('Test chained')

// Update the foobar class with baz
foobar.prototype.baz = function() {alert('BAZ worked!');return this}

foo('B').bar('1').baz().bar('2')
```

***Note:*** Click **`Run code snippet`** to see the output

That's it!

### Edit:

You can also do this with ES6 classes like:

```js
class foobar {
  constructor(text) {
    this.text = text;
  }
  bar(a) {alert(this.text+": "+a);return this}
}

const foo = text => new foobar(text)

foo('A').bar('Test').bar('Test chained')

// Update the foobar class with baz
foobar.prototype.baz = function() {alert('BAZ worked!');return this}

foo('B').bar('1').baz().bar('2')
```

Comment: Absolutely! If this answer addressed your question, please make sure to mark it as _accepted_.